# Why margin property is working on last container when parent container displays like flex?

Tags: html, css

Why margin-right is not working with last container element which parent have display:flex property?
For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<div style = " display: flex; border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; height: 400px;overflow-x: auto;"  >
<img style = " display: block; float:left;  width: 400px; height: 100px;margin-right: 10px;" src="images.jpg">
<img style = " display: block; float:left; width: 400px; height: 100px; margin-right: 10px;" src="images.jpg">
</div>
```

Jsfiddle [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95j1mxtn/)

Comment: Elements in a flex should not be floated, you are making the flex parent useless. So that could be one cause

Comment: Thanks, why margin-right is not working?

Comment: I have deleted float and the problem is not gone

Comment: If your elements are left aligned then the margin to the right won't do anything on the last element. Because there is nothing to margin from, try setting a border on the parent , you should see that the margin is indeed being applied just not visible to you

Comment: border is already set and margin is not being applied i can scroll it

Comment: just because you said "parent" which is div

Comment: Thanks for display flex correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Note the `width` property values, your mileage with it may vary.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parent {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
}

#inner {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: intrinsic; /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
  width: -moz-max-content; /* Firefox/Gecko */
  width: -webkit-max-content; /* Chrome */
  width: max-content;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="inner">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=1" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=2" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed all inline CSS. And I am bringing all the images under one class.

And of course, I removed **float** CSS because of flex. I use a CSS property **gap** for space between images.

Try this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test </title>
</head>

<style>
.container {
   display: flex; 
   border: 1px solid black; 
   gap: 20px; 
   padding: 20px;
}
.container img {
   border: 1px solid red; 
   width: 400px; 
   height: 100px;  
}

</style>
<body>

<div class="container">
<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/low-quality-stamp-sticker-seal-260nw-575960896.jpg">
<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/low-quality-stamp-sticker-seal-260nw-575960896.jpg">
<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/low-quality-stamp-sticker-seal-260nw-575960896.jpg">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gap is intended for grid elements not flex, it has a spotty support with Firefox being the only one to support it I guess :https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox

Comment: If I am not wrong, the **gap** property is also working with **flex**.

Comment: you arent wrong its just that it doesnt work with all browsers

Comment: Is it me or why i cant see any space between the last element and the right border?

Comment: @Justtoasktheneededquestions I don't know why do you need margin for the last element. You can use padding in the container class for the space between elements and the parent. 

If you need a specific margin for the last element, you can use `.container img:last-child `

Comment: I mean, i tried your code , and there is NO space between the last element and the right border even the padding property is set See answer above which is working right Thanks

Comment: Maybe your code works fine with Firefox which is mentioned above but i didnt use it so i cant see but thanks anyway